# Setting element width to an element width a percentage width not correct on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to set an element's width equal to another element's width.
The problem is that when the 2nd element has a percentage width, jQuery's .width() function returns the incorrect width *when the page is first loaded*.
If I do the same after the page is loaded, such as in an onclick function, then .width() returns the correct size of the element.
It is just when the page is first loaded, as if css hasn't finished calculating the actual elements width from the percentage.

Here is some code :

CSS :

```
#first {
    width:50%;
}
```

Javascript :

```
$(function(){
    function resizeResults() {
        $("#results").css("width", $("#first").width());
    }
    resizeResults();
});
```

So, that will not return the correct size of the #results element. If I call this function via an onclick method, then it sets it to the proper width.
 JavaScript/jQuery should account for css percentages being loaded before executing code, right?

Comment: Try putting everything inside of `$(window).load(function() { ... });` instead of `$(function() { ... });`. If that doesn't work, include all of your code so we have a complete example that replicates your issue.

Comment: Do you have an element with the id `#first` in your document or are you just relying on the css?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, I have an element with the id first.

Comment: @MichaelCoker This causes errors in my code, saying that $.fn is not defined.

Comment: @TiFiShu sounds like you have something else that's conflicting. You can try putting it in it's own script tag. like `<script>$(window).load(function() { ... });</script>`

Answer (score 2):

You must change this:

```
function resizeResults() {
    $("#results").css("width", $("#first").width());
}
```

to this:

```
function resizeResults() {
    $("#results").css("width", $("#first").width() + 'px');
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>        
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        div {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #acacac;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function ()
        {
            function resizeResults()
            {
                $("#results").css("width", $("#first").width() + 'px');
            }
            resizeResults();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="first" style="width:200px;">Div first</div>
    <div id="results" style="width:400px">Div result</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: or he can use `$("#results").width($("#first").width());` for it

Comment: I made the change. Same problem. Kinda weird that the code was working without the px.

Comment: @TiFiShu if you don't specify a type of value, like `px`, `%`, `em`, etc, then `$.width()`, `$.height()`, `$.css()`, etc will default to `px` with you assign either an integer or a number in a string like "100" to it.

Comment: @Ti Fi Shu i tested that and worked. Can i see your html code? I create a code snippet in my answer you can see that.